# SQL Performance slow when accessing most recent records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a MSSQL2005 database that has records dating back to 2004, there are currently just under 1,000,000 records in one particular table.

Thing is, if I run a report comparing 2009 data against 2010 data, 2008 against 2009, 2009 against 2009 or any combination of years before this year then results are returned in 1-5 seconds.

If however I run a report that includes 2011 data then the report takes ~6 minutes.

I've checked the data and it looks similar to previous years and is cross-referenced against the same data used in all of the reports.

It's as if the database has exceeded some limit; that data for this year has become fragmented and therefore harder to access. I'm not saying this is the case  but it may be for all I know.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Shaun.

Update:
Since posting the question I found **DBCC DBREINDEX *table_name*** which seems to have done the trick.

Comment: You also need to provide **WAY** more information on this.  What's the table structure?  What are the queries you are running? Any partitioning?  As Martin said,  you'll also need to check the execution plans.

Comment: also the two execution plans and indexes on the relevant tables.

Comment: It would be impossible to help you without having table schema, stored procedures, execution plans and other relevant information.

Comment: Check that all columns used in joins or ORDER BY clauses have indexes. Simple I know but easy to forget to add an index.

Comment: I had a same situation in the past. What I did was, inserted the desired records in the temporary table and then started the operation. In this way it started to give the results very quickly. But the worst part is, log file size because of I/O operations. Does his approach make sense ?

Comment: Note that `DBCC DBREINDEX` will cause the statistics to be updated as documented here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966425.aspx Instead of guessing what the problem is and running commands randomly you should analyse the problem whilst it is occurring so you know what the root problem is and can take steps to prevent it reoccurring.

Answer (score 5):

What do the execution plans look like? If different you might need to manually update statistics on the table as the newly inserted rows are likely to be disproportionately unrepresented in the statistics and it might thus choose a sub optimal plan.

See this blog post for an explanation of this issue [Statistics, row estimations and the ascending date column](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/)

Additionally check that your 2011 query isn't encountering blocking due to concurrent inserts or updates that do not affect queries against historic data.

Comment: +1 - I was thinking of concurrency myself.  I also suspect it may be partitioned on date, and the old partitions are inactive or they are inconsistently indexed.

Comment: I actually ran into this same problem at work a couple months ago and we noticed creating a filtered statistic for newer rows made the optimizer handle these rows much better.  Initially it was thinking because there was no data in the histogram that only one row would be returned so it wasn't doing readaheads and doing nested loop joins.